# What is the default package when compiling with BibTeX? (Using pdflatex)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, natbib

I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib) and understood that you can only be using either biblatex or natbib. However, I have been able to compile just fine with citations without writing neither `\usepackage{natbib}` nor `\usepackage{biblatex}`. To compile, I use the macOS terminal and run:
    pdflatex
    bibtex
    pdflatex
    pdflatex.

I am using texlive.

So, which package I am using when I don't specify the package? Or how is it possible that my file is compiling just fine when I am not writing specifically `\usepackage` ?

Comment: No particular package is used in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel includes support for `\cite` and the `\bibliography`/`\bibliographystyle` commands. However, this functionality is quite limited compared with `natbib` or `biblatex`.  For example, there is only the 'simple'`\cite` command, with no possibility to cite by name or similar. Moreover, only numerical bibliographies are supported by this method. Thus many users load additional packages to address what are common use cases.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I will have to start using a package then. I think I'll go for natbib

Comment: `biblatex+biber` is much more powerful and can be easily customised.

Comment: @Bernard No argument with that (cf. my LaTeX3 plans in this area) :)